# Basepoint free line bundles in $Pic^d(C)$ is an open set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $Pic^d(C)$ denote line bundles on $C$ with degree $d$. Is the subset of basepoint free line bundles an open set of $Pic^d(C)$? Many thanks!

Comment: Did you check the case of positive genus and $d=0$?

Comment: Yes in that case, only the trivial bundle has global sections and so the others are not globally generated. So the claim is not true. For $d\geq 2g+1$, everything is globally generated. In the intermediate $d$ values what happens?

Comment: I do not know what  you mean. For example, say genus is 2 and $d=2$. What happens? The globally generated ones are one dimensional and not two dimensional, so not dense.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am asking. How do we know that it's one dimensional in your example?

Comment: Well, there is a map $C\to Pic^2 d$, sending $P\to P+\sigma(P)$, where $\sigma$ is the hyperelliptic involution. The image is precisely the base point free line bundles.

Comment: Actually, the image is just one point and not one dimensional as I said. The above divisor for any $P$ corresponds to the canonical bundle.